# Parse file in C to read char

Tags: c, file, parsing, strtok

Let's say i have a file filled with random characters with whitespaces and \n included also random.

I want to look for this groups of chars, example: UU, II, NJ, KU. So the purpose is to read the file, look for this kind of groups and say how many are they in the file.

My problem is whitespace and \n, becase if i find one of these i should skip it and search again for the groups. I found a solution that could help me, the function **strtok_r** .

http://www.codecogs.com/reference/computing/c/string.h/strtok.php?alias=strtok_r

i think this will isolate full strings so i can read one at time.

Is it a good solution or should take other approach?

Comment: Reading the text file line by line and `strstr()` on the buffer. With `strtok_r()` you produce unnecessary tokens.

Comment: you should always think about the corner cases so we don't have to ask. what happens if you see UUU or KUU?

Comment: i dont, i will read char by char, but process 2 by 2, which mean ill see U, then see another U and count++, then ill read the next char and so on, if i find a whitespace or anythin different from a letter, i will discard it and the char that i've read before

Comment: using strtok_r() is a good solution because it can be used in a loop. If you pass NULL as first argument it will return you next token. while using strstr() you will have to maintain a pointer to track what have you already read. go for strtok_r()

Answer (score 4):

A naive solution would probably to read one character at a time, and when it's `'U'`, `'I'`, `'N'` or `'K'` then read another character to see if it's the next character in the group. If it is then increase a counter for that group. All other characters are simply discarded.

**Edit:** Example function:

```
int count_uu = 0;
int count_ii = 0;
int count_nj = 0;
int count_ku = 0;

void check_next_char(int expected, FILE *input, int *counter);

void count(FILE *input)
{
    int ch;  /* Character we read into */

    while ((ch = fgetc(input)) != EOF)
    {
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 'U':
            check_next_char('U', input, &count_uu);
            break;
        case 'I':
            check_next_char('I', input, &count_ii);
            break;
        case 'N':
            check_next_char('J', input, &count_nj);
            break;
        case 'K':
            check_next_char('U', input, &count_ku);
            break;

        default:
            /* Not a character we're interested in */
            break;
    }
}

/* This function gets the next character from a file and checks against
   an `expected` character. If it is same as the expected character then
   increase a counter, else put the character back into the stream buffer */
void check_next_char(int expected, FILE *input, int *counter)
{
    int ch = fgetc(input);
    if (ch == expected)
        (*counter)++;
    else
        ungetc(ch, input);
}
```

Comment: "If it is then increase a counter for that group" I will rephrase it to "implement a state machine."

Comment: a state machine seems something to implement yeah! what i wanted to do is not read whitespace and \n. Imagine that i have a really huge file, with strtok i wouldnt read those "chars" right?

Comment: @nunobhorta You have to read all characters, even whitespace. If you read char-by-char, as in my answer, or read blockwise doesn't matter. However you skip over it just like any other characters you are not interested in.

Comment: @nunobhorta Added one possible implementation of the solution outlined in my answer.

Comment: what if the file contains WUUT or NJQ the UU and NJ is counted but should not be

Comment: @BhavikShah image that the first four chars are WUUT, i will read W, but it's not part of the group so discard it, then next char is U, it's ok lets keep it, next its U, and we have a match, count :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use

https://github.com/leblancmeneses/NPEG/tree/master/Languages/npeg_c

if your search pattern becomes more difficult.

Here is a visual tool that can export C version:
http://www.robusthaven.com/blog/parsing-expression-grammar/npeg-language-workbench

Documentation for rule grammar: 
http://www.robusthaven.com/blog/parsing-expression-grammar/npeg-dsl-documentation

Rules

```
    (?<UU>): 'UU'\i; 
(?<II>): 'II'\i; 
(?<NJ>): 'NJ'\i; 
(?<KU>): 'KU'; // does not use \i so is case sensitive 

Find: UU / II / NJ / KU;
(?<RootExpression>): (Find / .)+;
```

Input 1:

```
 UU, II, NJ, KU  uu, ii, nJ, kU
```

Input 2:

```
jsdlfj023#uu, ii, nJ, kU $^%900oi)()*()  UU, II, NJ, KU
```